# Jquery event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have a jquery datatable, which is populated by an ajax call from DB when the user clicks a load button. The data is populated according to the date provided by user in a datepicker. I also have an export button to export the loaded datatable to excel. The export works fine with the datatable which comes with the page load. however multiple files are getting downloaded when datatable is populated again.

Here is the html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //export to excel Districts Remittance list
  $('#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').click(function() {
    $('<table>').append($("#remittanceDistrict").DataTable().$('tr').clone()).table2excel({
      exclude: ".noXls",
      name: "Districts Remittance",
      filename: 'Districts Remittance-' + date //do not include extension
   
  });
}


})
```

```html
<script src="js/dataTables/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<div id="month-group" class="input-group">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp</i>
  <asp:TextBox ID="selecttMonth" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><i class="fa fa-refresh" id="btnGo"></i>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnExcelDistrictsRemittance" class="export-to-excel" title="Export to Excel"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-2x"></i></button>
<table id="remittanceDistrict" class="table  table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <thead class="arrear-table">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>District</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

For exporting I am using table2excel.js plugin. Note:- I discovered that the `$('#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').click()` is firing multiple times . Any help is appreciated. Pardon if the question is too broad, I am new to the community

Comment: Clarify your question! To be more clearer in a question, you must identify the problems and difficulties you have.

Comment: There is an export to excel button in my page. That button is supposed to generate an excel file of the datatable. Also I am using ajax call for updating the datatable. Export to Excel is working fine when the page is loaded for the first time. But clicking the export button after an ajax call, multiple excel files with same data are generating. This is the issue.

Comment: @JoseMarques Please take a look at the updated question

Comment: This plugin is a hack on a hack, so you have problems with it. When I want to export tables, I use CSV files and PHP code.You have two solutions for your problem try to use PHP or JS to programmatically export your table, or try to find out a solution for the problem you have. If you want to use the first solution, I can try to help you, contact me when you have some code made. For more information on the second solution use the link for help: https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/commits/master

Comment: @JoseMarques i tried this: Deleted all the code inside  $('#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').click(), and put a alert inside that. now the code is like this `$('#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').click(function() {alert('test')}`; Now i see the alert is coming multiple times. That implies the problem is with the click event firing multiple times. How to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned earlier the problem was with the `$'(#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').click()` firing multiple times.

I solved it myself by `unbinding` all the `events` from the element.
Updated code below:

```
$('#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').unbind().click() {
    // whatever
}
```

**Update**

In newer versions of jquery you can use `off()` method

```
$'(#btnExcelDistrictsRemittance').Off().click() {
        // whatever
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok use the datatable plugin instead of table2excel.js plugin.

This solution has more options and works almost perfectly.

Example for excel only:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
/*
 * Table
 */
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

table.dataTable thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}

table.dataTable tfoot th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}

table.dataTable td.center,
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }

table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 { background-color: #D3D6FF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_2 { background-color: #DADCFF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_3 { background-color: #E0E2FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 { background-color: #EAEBFF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_2 { background-color: #F2F3FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_3 { background-color: #F9F9FF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<div>
<table id="table_id">   
        <thead>        
            <tr>            
                <th>Name</th>         
                <th>Age</th>               
                <th>Bot</th> 
            </tr>   
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr>       
                <td>John</td>
                <td>25</td>   
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_1">Select</button></td> 
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ana</td>
                <td>22</td>     
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_2">Select</button></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Diana</td>
                <td>23</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_3">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Lino</td>
                <td>32</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_4">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

All the options:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
/*
 * Table
 */
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

table.dataTable thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}

table.dataTable tfoot th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}

table.dataTable td.center,
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }

table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 { background-color: #D3D6FF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_2 { background-color: #DADCFF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_3 { background-color: #E0E2FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 { background-color: #EAEBFF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_2 { background-color: #F2F3FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_3 { background-color: #F9F9FF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<div>
<table id="table_id">   
        <thead>        
            <tr>            
                <th>Name</th>         
                <th>Age</th>               
                <th>Bot</th> 
            </tr>   
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr>       
                <td>John</td>
                <td>25</td>   
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_1">Select</button></td> 
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ana</td>
                <td>22</td>     
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_2">Select</button></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Diana</td>
                <td>23</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_3">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Lino</td>
                <td>32</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_4">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Important notes:

Some of the features may not work in the snippet (Print);

Initializations are required, without them the code does not work.

For more information visit this link: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Any doubt, just ask for my help.